# Iframe Video is not playing in FF but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I have one Url which opens race videos.
This video is opening properly in Chrome but not working in firefox.
This url returns mix content , this might be the reason that FF is not opening url in iframe. 
Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css"> body {scrolling:no;} iframe {position:fixed; top: 0px; left: 1050px; overlay:none;} z-index:1;}</style>
    <iframe src="https://replays.robertsstream.com/racereplays/replaysflash.php?cust=DRF&amp;stream=201702051549AQD7&amp;t=1491996358287&amp;h=95c7c217abbbb55213787b8df329ddbb" height="100%" width="-30px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does this page run on HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: My page runs on HTTP  , i tried to give HTTP an HTTPS both

Comment: I think that you answered the question yourself - this is a mixed content issue. Take a look at firefox's developer console, do you see any errors there?

Comment: @KobyDouek I did not get any error in console and also gone through many posts but not able to get proper answer.

Comment: Try removing the `width="-30px"` - This should not exist!

Comment: Any success with the suggestion above ?

Comment: @KobyDouek No luck :(
Getting below error in console , when i make url http.
  "Blocked loading mixed active content “http://replays.robertsstream.com/racereplays/replaysflash.php?cust=DRF&stream=201702051549AQD7&t=1491996358287&h=95c7c217abbbb55213787b8df329ddbb”"